# Why is my text looking blurry in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, cs6

The font is really blurry.
I don't know how to fix it.
Does anyone know? Please help me!
I tried everything and none of them worked.

[image]

Comment: Check the document resolution (Image > Image Size..)

Comment: Please name the font you used (OS is windows?). Describe what you tried and why it not worked ...

Comment: While I don't know why Photoshop 6+ is displaying text this way, I CAN say that it is historically unusual; in previous versions, unconverted text could be zoomed in indefinitely and still be super sharp. This was as it should be, because text is a vector object, not a pixel element, and until saved should be as sharp as your display can present it at any size or resolution. It's obviously not an OS issue, as text blurriness afflicts Windows users as well as Mac owners. I, for one, am disappointed that you cannot zoom in to see text better without it falling apart as if it actually was pixels

Comment: Event I found the same issue with my PS6 but it works fine with windows 7.

Comment: Apart from what the other answers said, the [hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinting) is horrible, e.g., the vertical strokes of the *M* differ in blackness.

Answer (score 11):

Your text looks blurry when you are editing it because it seems like your document is currently at **400% zoom** :)

Just double click on the zoom tool to get it back to 100%:

[image]

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning the resolution as part of the answer, because a 300 PPI document probably wouldn't look half as bad at 400% zoom.

Comment: That's correct, @Dom. You should post a seperate answer, clarifying that the resolution of the document is important to the display of text.

Answer (score 1):

Your resolution is too low. Click image, select image size, and raise the revolution. I usually set it around 300.